# CMFCToolBar buttons black when hover

Tags: image, mfc, toolbar

I have a problem with my CMFCToolBar created inside a CDialog. The problem is that when I move the mouse on top of any button, it's background becomes black, and all the colors of the button image are wrong.

This is the code I use to create the toolbar:

```
CMFCToolBarInfo tbParams;
tbParams.m_uiHotResID   = IDB_PNG_TOOLBAR_AMBIENTE;
tbParams.m_uiColdResID  = IDB_PNG_TOOLBAR_AMBIENTE;

if (!m_AmbienteTB->CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS, WS_CHILD | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC, CRect(1,1,1,1), IDR_AMBIENTE_TOOLBAR) || 
    !m_AmbienteTB->LoadToolBarEx(IDR_AMBIENTE_TOOLBAR, tbParams))
{ ... }
```

And these are the results.

Normal (it's correct):
[image]

Hover (wrong, as you can guess):
[image]

The toolbar image I load (IDB_PNG_TOOLBAR_AMBIENTE) is a PNG image created with Axialis IconWorkshop.

Comment: How did you create the tool bar image list?  Please show the code.

Comment: I don't. I use CMFCToolBar (introduced in MFC 2008 feature pack) and pass the toolbar imagestrip with the icons to LoadToolBarEx (in tbParams in my code above) and it loads the image list. The normal icon are loaded correctly, but the hover (hot) icons are wrong.

Comment: May be the transparent color isn't set correct. Also it seams that the colors are very different.

Comment: Yes, it's true. The colors are very different, but it doesn't make sense because it's the same image. And for the transparent color, well I don't specify it because it's not asked. Since it's a PNG it has a trasparent background.

Comment: xMRi's comment is the exact reason why I load the button images from an image list that I can control.

Comment: It looks like the hover colours have been reduced to 4-bit.

Comment: Yes, it seems so. But I can't explain why.